# Language Barrier - A study on languages

Tags: word, language, crosswords

[image: Language Barrier - Stolen, "Borrowed" English only]

(Author Note) A while ago I made some puzzles for a now defunct puzzle hunt project, here's one of them. The answer to this ([and some other puzzles of said hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22A+study+on%22+is%3Aquestion)) is two words. The puzzle itself is fully contained within the image above. Author notes don't matter.

### TRANSCRIPT

#### Down:

1. Ennemi du Titanic
2. Pista per la poggia
3. Element für fünf Cent
4. Sangre de perrito caliente
9. Tre angoli
10. Špízové mäso
11. Cantidad limitada permitida
13. Reste inconnu

#### Across:

5. Lois aveugles
6. Kleiner bruder des Minenwerfers
7. Tal ohne Gletscher
8. Noeud délicieux
12. Raccolta di lettere
14. Miedo repentino

Comment: Also, if you want to search to be restricted to only puzzles made *by you*, use [this link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22A+study+on%22+is%3Aquestion+user%3A78764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> [CHALLENGER DEEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenger_Deep)

The filled in puzzle is

> [image]

Explanation

> Each answer is an English word loaned from another language. Surprisingly, the clues are not in the language the answer word was loaned from.

1. Ennemi du Titanic

> French "Enemy of the Titanic" Iceberg

2. Pista per la poggia

> Italian "Track for the rain" Gutter

3. Element für fünf Cent

> German "Element for five cents" Nickel

4. Sangre de perrito caliente

> Spanish "Blood of a hot dog" Ketchup

9. Tre angoli

> Italian "Three angles" Triangle

10. Špízové mäso

> Slovak "Skewered meat" Kebab

11. Cantidad limitada permitida

> Spanish "Permitted limited quantiy" Quota

13. Reste inconnu

> French "Remains unknown" Anonymous

5. Lois aveugles

> French "Blind laws" Justice

6. Kleiner bruder des Minenwerfers

> German "Little brother of the Mortar" Howitzer

7. Tal ohne Gletscher

> German "Valley without glacier" Fjord

8. Noeud délicieux

> French "Delicious knot" Pretzel

12. Raccolta di lettere

> Italian "Collection of letters" Alphabet

14. Miedo repentino

> Spanish "Sudden fear" Panic

Finally, take the red highlighted letters

> and arrange them according to the Roman numerals and you get CHALLENGER DEEP

Comment: A complete answer! Wonderfully executed, as for the languages used, I preferred using language that still have the standard alphabet.

Comment: 13. "Remain anonymous" would be better